# Android mail client, remote process or not

Tags: android, android-service

As relatively new to the android platform I was given the task of implementing a email client. For this I want to use an service that allways run in the background (client should allways receive emails as soon as the server gets them, requirement from the customer).

Now I've looked into the Service's in android, but can't seem to find any good answer on whether or not the Service should be local or remote.

What would the main advantages/disadvantages be with choosing one over the other? Bare in mind the Service must be running at all times. I know, I know. BAD. But it is essential to core features of the application.

Comment: "Bare in mind the Service must be running at all times" -- no, it must not. For starters, it *will* not "be running at all times", as the user and the OS can get rid of your app from memory at any time, for any reason. Any design that assumes that a "Service must be running at all times" is simply flawed.

Comment: I am aware that I can not assume that the Service is running at all times. But due to the environment/context in which this application will operates it is crucial that mail gets to the phone in the shortest amount of time possible. I just haven't figured out how yet, GCM seems like a viable option if it wakes up the Service when it receives an Intent. The other options is simply "make sure the Service is running". All input on matter will ofcourse be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I don't know the reason why you can want to use another process. If you will - you'll have to deal with Inter-process communications, with all this AIDL, Parcels etc.

And if you will keep the same process - it will be much easier to transfer the data between your components.

The only reasons to make several processes I think is to try to avoid Android Heap budget limitation. You can try to move heavy objects between processes and try to double your limit. However I think you don't need this, also it's bad way too.

So I will recommend not to play with processes and keep things as simple as possible.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

First, the correct/efficient way to do instant notifications from a remote server like this on Android is to use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). GCM lets you remotely wake up the device by sending an Intent to your application, which you can then use as a signal to fetch the message from the server, post a notification to the status bar, etc.

Doing what you're describing with an eternally running service will have a significant effect on battery life unless you get everything exactly right. Keeping the phone awake all the time is not a viable option. Use GCM and do not roll your own solution for this.

But since your question was more general about whether to run a service in a separate process, in general simpler is better and in this case simpler means running in the same process. You'll have access to all of the various elements of your app's process in memory and in general you will probably have a much easier time. Your events will all happen on the same main thread's Looper. Everything will be much more straightforward.

If you don't already have a very good reason for using a separate process for your service, you should run it in the same process.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly look into to GCM. Just one quick question though. Given CommonWares comment to the origin post, the Service may not be running at all times. Will GCM start the IntentService if that is not the case?

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly look into the possibility of using GCM.

Comment: Yes, your relevant app components will be started just as they would if they received an intent from any other source.